# Mathematica giving wrong output

Tags: numerics, evaluation

I have defined (very roughly):

```
U1[x_,y_] := 1/4 ( 1 - f[x,y] - g[x,y]);
U2[x_,y_] := 1/4 ( 1 - f[x,y] + g[x,y]);
U3[x_,y_] := 1/4 ( 1 + f[x,y] - g[x,y]);
U4[x_,y_] := 1/4 ( 1 + f[x,y] + g[x,y]);

U1[1,2]+U2[1,2]+U3[1,2]+U4[1,2]
```

Clearly, the output should be 1 for any value of x and y (except inf). Technically, I have U1,U2,U3,U4,f,g as functions of 7 parameters instead of two as I have taken here and the values of f and g are of the order `10^16` to `10^20` or so for the parameters that I have which are of order `10^-1` to `10^2`.

I am not getting 1 as output when I run the code. I think the problem is because what my output statement does is calculate each U separately which results in something like `1/4 + 3.5012 *10^20` which becomes merely `3.5012*10^20` and so on which could be messing up with the final result.

Can anyone please help me get correct result? I can provide the notebook with the actual code if it is required, but it is of several pages and involves long formulae.

(Please excuse my bad formatting etc, I am very very new to SE and mathematica as well)

Comment: Look at documentation for `Simplify`, e.g., `Simplify[U1[1,2]+U2[1,2]+U3[1,2]+U4[1,2]]`

Comment: @ciao I am getting "simplified to ComplexInfinity". Can I use [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43102/getting-error-fullsimplifyinfd-simplified-to-complexinfinity) to get where the division by zero is coming from?

Comment: yes, you could give that a whirl.

Comment: @ciao Could you please also tell me if I am getting numerical output only because the inf expression is being simplified to 0? By which I mean that when calculating in symbolic form I can see the error of "simplified to ComplexInfinity" but when putting in values it is not coming up.

Comment: I'm afraid Mathematica is being given the wrong input (so the subject of the post is incorrect). Others have mentioned possible use of `Simplify`, `Expand`, and the like. But one should also be aware of issues from numerical analysis such as truncation error and cancellation error, either or both of which almost certainly are involved in the results you obtain.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you. I will look into these. Can I use higher precision to tackle some of the issues? For e.g. `$MinPrecision = 40`

Comment: You can use higher precision, but the `$MinPrecision` setting will have no effect unless all inputs are either exact values or at least have 40 digits of precision. In particular, machine reals will contaminate the computations.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You are undoubtedly running into a precision problem.  Numbers like `10^20` are beyond machine precision, and subtracting numbers of that magnitude with machine precision accuracy will give you large numerical errors.  You don't say specifically what your `f` and `g` functions consist of, but you need to make them return exact rational numbers, or at least set the digits of precision significantly higher that 20 if `10^20` are the numbers you are playing with.  An example of increasing the digits would be:

```
f[x_, y_] := 3.005`30 x + 2.3`30 10^20 y

f[x,y]
(*3.00500000000000000000000000000 x + 2.30000000000000000000000000000*10^20 y*)

f[1, 2]
(*4.60000000000000000003005000000*10^20*)
```

Comment: Can I set `$MinPrecision =40` and be assured that things will be fine? Atleast on precision part?

Comment: Give it a try. Without knowing your functions, I can't try much myself.